# Using QGIS to contour in Fedora 26?

Tags: qgis, contour, fedora

I have a problem with QGIS. When using the contour tool I get the following error:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
>   you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Do other tools work?

Comment: Please add the steps how you installed QGIS. Does gdal_contour work inside a terminal?

Comment: Which exact contour tool?